# How the compiler can prove that memory safety?

Tags: ios, swift

When I read *The Swift Programming Language: Memory Safety,* I was confused by the section [Conflicting Access to Properties](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/MemorySafety.html#ID571):

> The code below shows that the same error appears for overlapping write
> accesses to the properties of a structure that’s stored in a global
> variable.
>
> ```swift
> var holly = Player(name: "Holly", health: 10, energy: 10)
> balance(&holly.health, &holly.energy)  // Error
> ```
>
> In practice,
> most access to the properties of a structure can overlap safely. For
> example, if the variable `holly` in the example above is changed to a
> local variable instead of a global variable, the compiler can prove
> that overlapping access to stored properties of the structure is
> safe:
>
> ```swift
> func someFunction() {
>     var oscar = Player(name: "Oscar", health: 10, energy: 10)
>     balance(&oscar.health, &oscar.energy)  // OK 
> }
> ```
>
> In the example above, Oscar’s health and energy are passed as the two in-out parameters to `balance(_:_:)`. The compiler can prove that memory
> safety is preserved because the two stored properties don’t interact
> in any way.

How the compiler can prove that memory safety?

Comment: I've often wondered about this same issue from the opposite angle, namely why *can't* the compiler prove memory safety in the first example.  Surely the compiler knows the memory layout of a global variable just as well as a local one, and should be able to see whether `health` and `energy` properties alias one another in either case.  I have some speculation, but not an actual answer.  Good question.

Comment: While this is an interesting question, I don't think SO is the correct forum for it. I would suggest you ask this in the [Swift forums](https://forums.swift.org), where you can find experts that are more intimate with the functionality of the compiler.

Comment: Have also created [a topic](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-the-compiler-can-prove-that-memory-safety/50542) on Swift forums.

Answer (score 1):

Being inside a function scope gives the compiler the certainty of which operations will be executed on the `struct` and when. The compiler knows how `structs` work, and how and when (relative to the time the function is called) the code inside a function is executed.

In a global or larger scope, the compiler loses visibility over what could be modifying the memory, and when, so it cannot assure safety.

Comment: Are you suggesting that it's a matter of thread-safety, and not a memory aliasing issue?

Comment: @ChipJarred or a combination of those things.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of multiple threads. When "holly" is a global variable, multiple threads could access the global variable at the same time, and you are in trouble. In the case of a local variable, that variable exists once *per execution of the function*. If multiple threads run someFunction() simultaneously, each thread has its own "oscar" variable, so there is no chance that thread 1's "oscar" variable access thread 2's oscar variable.

Comment: If it's a thread-safety issue one has the same (or very similar) problem with non-struct values (data races).   I suspect that it has to do with pass-by-reference not merely passing pointers behind the scenes as it would in C or C++.  Basically if it were merely about data races, then any reference to a global, even a single one, would be problematic, and is an inconsistency in the design of the language.  I'm not sure of the actual answer, but it seems to me that it for it to be a consistent language design, it would need to be a memory aliasing problem, not just a data race issue.

Comment: This answer and the one by EmilioPelaez both jive with another answer given on [the Swift forum question](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-the-compiler-can-prove-that-memory-safety/50542/4) created by this original poster. I accept these answers since they're better than the one given in the Swift Language Guide. But @ChipJarred has a good point. If the reason is because the compiler thinks it's too risky to allow this kind of access for global variables, then why doesn't the compiler also think it's risky to access other global objects in a similar fashion? I agree this does seem inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

An answer from *Andrew_Trick* on [Swift Forums](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-the-compiler-can-prove-that-memory-safety/50542/2):

> "don't interact" is a strong statement. The compiler simply checks that each access to 'oscar' in the call to 'balance' can only modify independent pieces of memory ('heath' vs 'energy'). This is a special case because any access to a struct is generally modeled as a read/write to the entire struct value. The compiler does a little extra work to detect and allow this special case because copying the 'oscar' struct in situations like this would be inconvenient.